# Managing coordinates and projections for zonal statistics on global data

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, zonal-statistics

I am working with a global raster that is in the World Mollweide (EPSG: 54009) projection. I also have a set of polygons from different parts of the globe that are shapefiles in the WGS 84 (EPSG: 4326) CRS.

I am well aware that the best approach for summing the raster scores within each polygon would be to project the shapefiles and then conduct zonal statistics with both layers in Mollweide (since projections between rasters involve resampling of the grid cell values). However, the zonal statistics will be part of a larger geoprocessing setup where the conversion of the polygons/shapefiles to Mollweide may not be as feasible as having the raster data in WGS 84 right from the start.

I was therefore wondering if there would be an additional way to conduct zonal statistics with both layers in WGS 84 while minimizing the errors that result from converting the raster files from Mollweide to WGS 84?

I have conducted a few analyses on how the results would differ if I were to use both the raster + shapefiles in Mollweide vs. having them both in WGS 84. What I found is that, relative to Mollweide, WGS 84 tends to overestimate the sums of scores within each polygon for locations that are further away from the equator while it underestimates the sums for locations that are close to the Equator.

If is it helpful, I am happy to provide some sample data and more details on how I compared the sums with both data inputs.